# How can I do string operations in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, string, xpath

I have the following code block in my xslt;

```
      <xsl:when test="StatusData/Status/Temperature > 27">
        <td bgcolor="#ffaaaa">              
          <xsl:value-of select="StatusData/Status/Temperature" />              
        </td>
      </xsl:when>
```

But as you might guess when the value is 34,5 instead of 34.5 it is recognised as a string which makes integer comparison not possible. I thought replacing , with . would be solution that needs a char replace. My question is how I can do this
or
It would be great to know more about string operations in XSLT...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a `translate()` function in XPath:

```
test="translate(StatusData/Status/Temperature, ",", ".") > 27"
```

Additionally you should make use of the number function, which converts it's argument to a number (or NaN, if that fails):

```
test="number(translate(StatusData/Status/Temperature, ",", ".")) > 27.0"
```

See the [documentation for `translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-translate) and the [documentation for `number()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-number) at w3.org.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx a lot.

it works but with one simple modification:

```
test="number(translate(StatusData/Status/Temperature, ',', '.')) > 27.0"
```

by the way it is not about XSLT it is about XPath :) good to learn...

Answer (score 0):

In XSL 2 you can also use the full-fledged `replace()` which even supports regex patterns.